# Why isn't my Singleton.getInstance() executing in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm a little bit new to Android.
If I have a Singleton below does the init function automatically get called when the singleton is first initialsed?

```
public class Singleton  {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
    private Singleton() {};

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return(INSTANCE);
    }

    void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "is this firing");
    }
}
```

I'm referencing the Singleton the first time in the MainActivity but I can't see the output "is this firing" in the LogCat:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Singleton model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        model = Singleton.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I've used swift/ios a bit and in an ios app when I call Singleton.sharedInstance for the first time init() runs and things get initialized. I can't recall what happens in Java.

```
class Singleton {
    private struct Static {
        static var instance: Singleton?
    }

    class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
        if (!Static.instance != nil) {
            Static.instance = Singleton()
        }
        return Static.instance!
     }


    private init() {
         print("initialised first time")
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think `init` will be called if you don't call it?

Comment: don't you need to init `Singleton` class as an instance, do you??

Comment: you didn't call init() method so how log will display ??

Comment: *If I have a Singleton below does the init function automatically get called when the singleton is first initialised?* No. Call it if you want to call an `init()`, the constructor would be the equivalent place to put it. Also, couldn't you have tried it at this point? `private Singleton() { init(); }`

Comment: Why you think `init()` will be called.

Comment: I just vote you up because some hipster user who did not try Swift/Kotlin before vote you down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the init method during instance creation. Do this:

```
public class Singleton  {

    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;

    private Singleton() {
        init();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return(INSTANCE);
    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "is this firing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as I know in swift `init` get called automatically when you initialize a class like the `Kotlin` in case of java you need to call the init method from the class `constructor` like this

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;
    private Singleton() {
        init();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return(INSTANCE);
    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "is this firing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`init()` is  a function that you have defined only but haven't invoked from anywhere else.

invoke init() from `inside your private constructor where init gets called only once` when your singleton object gets created for the first time:

```
private Singleton() {
 init();
}
```

if you wish to call it `every time`, `put init() function inside getInstance()` :

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = new Singleton();
            }
            init();
            return(INSTANCE);
        }
```

Check your LogCat window now.